# Anaconda - package installed but module not found

Tags: python, anaconda, igraph

installed the igraph package using conda install

```
conda install -c conda-forge igraph
```

it shows on anaconda index

[image: anaconda index]

and on anaconda prompt using conda list

[image: anaconda prompt]

but when I try to import it on jupyter notebook, I get:

[image: jupyter notebook]

Comment: What is the output of `import sys; print(sys.executable)` in the Jupyter console? Is it the same python executable as in the Anaconda installation?

Comment: C:\Users\<myname>\Anaconda3\python.exe.

I'm pretty sure it is

Comment: Did you try the import without the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: I mean, inside a regular python shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install `python-igraph` not `igraph`, i.e. `conda install -c conda-forge python-igraph`. `igraph` is the C core, while `python-igraph` is the Python interface of `igraph`.

Comment: Maybe it needs a description? I see an empty description field in the OP's screenshot.